# should I cite @articles & @inproceedings from different .bib files?

Tags: elsarticle

[image: .bbl file screenshot]I have the articles & inproceedings in the file `dtbase.bib` in the following manner:

```
@article{Russell17012003,
author = {Russell, Philip}, 
title = {Photonic Crystal Fibers},
year = {2003}, 
journal = {Science} 
}


@inproceedings{Hansen:02, 
author = {Kim P. Hansen and Jacob Riis Jensen and Christian Jacobsen and           Harald R. Simonsen and Jes Broeng and Peter M. W. Skovgaard and Anders Petersson    and Anders Bjarklev}, 
booktitle = {Optical Fiber Communications Conference}, 
journal = {Optical Fiber Communications Conference},
keywords = {Nonlinear optics, fibers},
publisher = {Optical Society of America},
title = {Highly Nonlinear Photonic Crystal Fiber with Zero-Dispersion at     1.55\&\#x00B5;m}, 
year = {2002},
pages = {FA9},
}
```

While my tex file try.tex reads as-

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{blablabla}

\author{bla bla}

\address{blabla}

\begin{abstract}
blalbal

\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}

bla

\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}


\section{Introduction}

 microstructured \cite{Russell17012003}  blabla birefringence     etc.\cite{Knight96} high nonlinearity required blabla \cite{Hansen:02} 


\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num} 
\bibliography{dtbase}

\end{document}

\endinput
```

Whenever I put articles & inproceedings in the same bib file, after compiling the tex file it shows - the following warning -

```
Citation 'Hansen:02' on page 1 undefined.
```

and it doesn't show the inproceeding. What am I doing wrong?  I am using Texmaker for editing both the .bib file &  .tex file.

Comment: The long blank spaces in Hansen:02, fields author and title, suggest that you have line breaks there, which aren't allowed

Comment: @musicman  they somehow popped up here.  In the actual code they're fine, no line breaks.  Still doesn't work.

Comment: pls check the biber error log file .blg for errors. Are you running pdflatex - biber - pdflatex?

Comment: yes i did the pdflatex - biber - pdflatex-pdflatex sequence.  I see the .aux & .bbl files, but i see no .blg file out there. fyi there is a text file created from pdflatex log.

the main file is try.tex.  the output files are- try.aux, try.bbl, try.out

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. It compiles just fine. Please edit your question and give us a full working MWE which shows the problem.

Comment: Just in case someone is interested in the answer to the question in the title: You *can* use different `.bib` files for different types, but it doesn't really make sense to do so. It is much more useful to separate `.bib` files by topic or by the document you are currently writing. So I would say the answer is: You shouldn't.

Comment: Now to the problem in the question body. The fact that you cannot find a  `.blg` file implies quite heavily that Biber (or BibTeX) didn't run. What does the `.bbl` contain? Does the `.log` complain? Did you run from within an editor (refer to [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864))? Can you try running the commands from the command line (`pdflatex try`, `biber try`, `pdflatex try`, `pdflatex try`)? Then please report the screen output of the Biber run, the `.blg` and `.log` files.

Comment: Just for sake of completeness a link to [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864).

Comment: You might also want to have a look at the `title` of `Hansen:02`, the `1.55\&\#x00B5;m` bit looks like a butchered HTML conversion of `1.55µm`. (At first I thought all those characters would make Biber uncomfortable, but it ploughed through.)

Comment: @moewe  I have known latex only for 2 days, so here's the answers as far as I could-

Comment: Please create a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) so we can have a look at what might be your problem. We don't even know which package you use for the bibliography. Maybe you don't even use `biblatex` in which case you shouldn't run Biber but BIbTeX.

Comment: @moewe  I have known latex only for 2 days, so here's the answers as far as I could-
-.bbl snapshot is attached to the question
- The log gives a warning about only undefined citation Hansen:02.
- I ran everything using Texmaker.
-I don't understand what it means running from the command line. 
- I dont see the .blg  and .log file in the current directory with .Tex file. Is it possible that they are generated somewhere else ? 

Am I missing something very basic here ? I am using the package elsartice-num for elsevier papers, and I ran Bibtex indeed. Wait I'm giving an MWE in a few minutes

Comment: Please embed any kind of file as paste-able text and not in a picture. The `.bbl` file looks all right, `Hansen:02` is defined there...

Comment: I have given both .tex & .bib files here. Since you said .bbl is all right, I'm not just rembedding it. oh I had another citation named Knight96, just not shown in the .bib file.

Comment: The MWE worked fine for me. You should try and compile from the command line (google how to do that if you don't know how it works), note the output of the runs and find the `.log` and `.blg`  files.

Answer (score 3):

[Elsarticle](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle) (`elsarticle-num`) uses the [natbib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib)-package, so you need `bibtex` for the references, not `biber`, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25702/46389) for more information.

Run the following example in the order `pdflatex file` - `bibtex file` - `pdflatex file` - `pdflatex file` (without fileendings). It should work.

The entry `Knight96` was missing in your question so I made one up.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{dtbase.bib}
@article{Russell17012003,
author = {Russell, Philip}, 
title = {Photonic Crystal Fibers},
pages = {358-362}, 
year = {2003}, 
doi = {10.1126/science.1079280}, 
journal = {Science} 
}

@inproceedings{Hansen:02, 
author = {Kim P. Hansen and Jacob Riis Jensen and Christian Jacobsen and           Harald R. Simonsen and Jes Broeng and Peter M. W. Skovgaard and Anders Petersson    and Anders Bjarklev}, 
booktitle = {Optical Fiber Communications Conference}, 
journal = {Optical Fiber Communications Conference},
keywords = {Nonlinear optics, fibers},
publisher = {Optical Society of America},
title = {Highly Nonlinear Photonic Crystal Fiber with Zero-Dispersion at     1.55\&\#x00B5;m}, 
year = {2002},
pages = {FA9},
}

@book{Knight96,
title = {How to become a Knight},
author = {Notaknight Yet},
year = {1296},
publisher = {Rich Merchant},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num} 
\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{blablabla}
\author{bla bla}
\address{blabla}
\begin{abstract}
blalbal
\end{abstract}
\begin{keyword}
bla
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}
 microstructured \cite{Russell17012003}  blabla birefringence     etc.\cite{Knight96} high nonlinearity required blabla \cite{Hansen:02} 

\section*{References}
\bibliography{dtbase}

\end{document}
```